# Understanding how Xcode works with vector files

Tags: ios, xcode, svg, vector

I have a game that is extremely procedural and because of this one of the textures in the games can end up covering the space of (113 x 10) to (682 x 768) on iPad retina.  Furthermore it isn't always even in the same aspect ratio. Furthermore the unscaled texture has to be at an aspect ratio of about 2:11 making things awkward.

I can not figure out how Xcode perceives pdf vector files.

For example the first time I made my svg into a pdf and followed all the instructions for making a single vector slot it ended up being all pixelated/anti-aliased on some devices.  And I know that .pdf vectors can be rasterized to any resolution without loosing quality!  So I am pretty sure Xcode compiles vectors into bitmaps for the SKTexture.  And as far as I can tell the amount of pixels that it rasterizes from the vector is not even variable on a device.

For example after that one I scaled up the svg to double the pts of its dimensions and exported it.  Now on some devices the texture looked perfect yet on others it looked like a rasterized mess!  And it didn't seem to happen because of one device resolution being bigger then the other.

So then I decided to scale the vector one more time so at this point it had 4x more points then the vector started as.  Things worked wonderfully, until I tested on the iPhone 6 and instead of being beautiful the texture got blacked out, I am fairly certain this is because the texture was to big for Spritekit.  There is no happy medium I can find.

My goal is to get this vector file looking great on every device regardless of how it is scaled.

I have looked around to see what SpriteKit uses for its pt to pixel conversions and I haven't found any numbers that check out.  How I can make my texture work for this project?  How does Spritekit decide how many pixels to rasterize a vector as when I make an SKTexture.

Edit:

Here are some hypothetical questions.

H1.  How many points wide and tall would a pdf vector need to be for it to be able to be up to these dimensions on any device.  width = width of device, height = height of device / 2.  So basically if I had a vector I knew was going to occupy that space what should its dimensions (in points) be?

H2.  Is the amount of pixels rasterized for every point directly proportionate to the amount of pixels on the display or is their more then just pixels on a screen?

Comment: My impression is that Xcode will convert a PDF to PNG using the nominal dimensions of the PDF as the base size (the 1x scale version) and that it will make other PNGs that fill in the 2x, 3x, etc. at those dimensions but denser. You could try just keeping your SVG and using a rendering library (I wrote SVGgh) to convert it at run time, if this was reasonable performance-wize.

Comment: @Glenn Howes that is so awesome! Where can I find/buy svgh?

Comment: Cause if I just had a library that would allow me to specify the dimensions the svg is rendered as that would be perfect!

Comment: SVGgh is available on GitHub. You render in whatever dimensions you deem reasonable.  https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh